# Require in mustache template the same on node as on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache, hogan.js, isomorphism

This question uses Hogan as an example but applies to any template.

I am trying to make something isomorphic (work on both the client and server). On the client if I require in a mustache file:

```
var tpl = require('./something.ms');
```

Then browserify + a transform detects this is a mustache file by extension and `tpl` is an Object and one of the functions is `.render`.

I would like exactly the same result if I was to run the above line with NodeJS.

By default Node just expects this file to be a javascript file and so the result just looks like this and errors:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <h1>some html</h1> ...
```

Comment: If you look [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) in the node doc for File modules that the `require()` function can load, it says that it will load three types of files `.js` files (script files to be loaded as scripts in the node module format), `.json` files (parsed as json text) and `.node` files which are compiled add-on modules.  I don't see any indication that node's `require()` can load javascript that isn't in the module format or HTML.  I'm sure there are other ways to load that.

Comment: FYI, using express and handlebars (which is mustache-like) with node, I just pass the name of the template file to `response.render()` and the engine takes care of loading the template file for me - I don't have to load it myself.  You haven't shown your server-side code that uses the template so we don't have any idea how you're trying to do that, but I'm guessing that if you're loading it yourself, there's probably an easier way.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks but I wanted to avoid using express - I could load the template myself but I wanted it to be exactly the same as the client which simply does a require and browserify + a transform detects it is a mustache file and handles it accordingly

Comment: Avoiding lots of pre-built server infrastructure code is unlikely to save you time.  You can still share lots of code between client and server even if you use express - you just have to learn how you do it.  The browser `require()` is simply not the same as the node `require()` you can either write some different code on the server to handle your templates or you can find or code a new version of `require()` that does what you want.  End of story.

Comment: @jfriend00 I agree and the server will be using express, but I am making an existing large clientside app isomorphic (as in render the first pageview on the server) and was seeing if there was a way of doing it without modifying the clientside code and just having a router which worked on both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised this wasn't easier to find out about!

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions

Unfortunately it is deprecated though "Unlikely to go away". I actually think it solves a problem I haven't otherwise seen a solution for in this kind of instance.

```
var Hogan = require('hogan.js');
require.extensions['.ms'] = function(mod, file){
    var tpl = fs.readFileSync(file, {encoding:'UTF-8'});
    mod.exports = Hogan.compile(tpl);
}
```

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/QsOEWvptQpA), `require.extensions` is flagged as deprecated in order to discourage its use and not to warn about a removal in a future release. The discussion also recommend the pre-compilation of the files (i.e. compile the `something.ms` into like `something-ms.js`, then include the js file for both nodejs and browser use). I guess using a third-party library to reproduce the `require.extensions` feature without using the core `require.extensions` would also be acceptable. I would personally use your solution.